# Needed help?? installing Tensorflow-GPU for Win 10 Pro 9-2-18

Tags: tensorflow

1.Create a new environment through conda create --name tftest. (You can replace tftest with e.g. the name of your current project.)
2.Activate that new environment through activate tftest.
3.Install TF into this environment through conda install tensorflow.
4.Ensure that you're in the right environment through where python (which should produce a path containing "tftest").
5.Run Python through python.
6.import tensorflow as tf in a shell in that environment.

Thanks to great community as I found this thanks to another post!!!

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version [1.6.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.6.0), prebuild binaries need AVX instructions.
There are some bug reports by people who tried to use the precompiled binaries but whose doesn't support AVX instructions and got the same error as you posted here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17761

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17386

Maybe you have this problem? If yes, you may have to build tensorflow from [sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) or downgrade to tensorflow 1.5.1.